# How to test SnapshotStateList in mockk

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, mockk

I want to test `mutableStateListOf`. I am using Mockk library in my project.

```
class MovieViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    var movieList = mutableStateListOf<MovieItem>()

    fun addItems(itemList: ArrayList<MovieItem>) {
        movieList.addAll(itemList)
    }
    // more code in here
}
```

I made a test like this way

```
class MovieViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val executorRule: TestRule = TestMainCoroutineRule()

    @get:Rule
    val koinTestRule = KoinTestRule.create()

    private val subject by lazy { spyk(MovieViewModel()) }
    @MockK private lateinit var mockItemList: ArrayList<MovieItem>

    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxed = true)
    }

    // more test in here

    @Test
    fun `addItems - WHEN method is called THEN should add all value`() {
        val spyKMovieList = spyk<SnapshotStateList<MovieItem>>()
        subject.movieList = spyKMovieList
        subject.addItems(mockItemList)
        verify { mockItemList.addAll(mockItemList) }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Verification failed: call 1 of 1: ArrayList(mockItemList#6).addAll(eq(ArrayList(mockItemList#6)))) was not called.

Calls to same mock:
1) ArrayList(mockItemList#6).size()
2) ArrayList(mockItemList#6).size()
3) ArrayList(mockItemList#6).iterator()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are verifying that the mock adds itself to itself, this doesn't make sense.

```
verify { mockItemList.addAll(mockItemList) }
```

You could `verify` that the class under test `MovieViewModel` has had it's method `addItems` called but there is no point since you've called it in your test.

Instead, The class under test `MovieViewModel` should not be mocked.
Test that the classes mutableStateListOf contains the expected elements after you've called `addItems`.

```
assertEquals(subject.movieList, mockItemList)
```

The test could look like this; You add your mocked list of items *(this list doesnt need to be a mock)* to the class through it's `addItems` method then **assert** that the class' list contains the same elements that you passed it.

```
@Test
fun `addItems - WHEN method is called THEN should add all value`() {
    subject.addItems(mockItemList)
    assertEquals(subject.movieList, mockItemList)
}
```